# Directory Authorization Issue on visual studio c#

Tags: c#, file, permissions, system32

I create a writing test to check for permission to write.
The test is

```
  try
        {
            string filePath = String.Format(Path.Combine(path, Path.GetRandomFileName()));
            File.WriteAllText(filePath, @"0");
            File.Delete(filePath);
            return true;
        }
        catch (IOException uex)
        {
         //SomeErrorMessage
        } 
         catch (SecurityException uex)
        {
        }
        catch (UnauthorizedAccessException uex)
        {
        }
```

When I try to write on C:\Windows\System32 as a normal user (I can't write here), the file writeAllText seems to be able to write in that directory but if I comment the delete row, I can't see the file in that directory ( I use the prompt as administrator,too) and if I wrote  File.ReadAllText(filePath), I can read that file. Why I can create a file in C:\Windows\System32 and why I can see that file only with File.ReadAllText(filePath)?

Comment: Have you tried turning off the UAC (User Account Control) and see if you can write to it? Please take note that if you are using Windows 8.1 you should also modify the EnabledLUA registry key to disable UAC temporarily. This might have something to do with it.

Comment: I think you're right! I disabled UAC and now I can write on C:\System32 even if in property I have read-only permission.